# No sandbox user '_apt' on the system, can not drop privileges

Tags: apt, gnome, software-installation

I removed the `_apt` user by accident, and every time I update the software, I get this message: `No sandbox user '_apt' on the system, can not drop privileges`.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Just an FYI: You don't *actually* need to worry about those warnings, in the long term, `_apt` is just used in sandboxes for building and such; what you're seeing is just a warning and not an actual error, everything should work fine as-is.  (I get the same exact message in my older `sbuild` chroots where I build Ubuntu packaging, when the system didn't have the `_apt` user by default, even though my system is 16.04.)

Answer (score 7):

Add the `_apt` user back to `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`:

```
$ sudo grep _apt /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
/etc/passwd:_apt:x:168:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
/etc/shadow:_apt:*:17121:0:99999:7:::
```

YMMV: The `_apt` `UID` on my system is `168`, and yours may not be `168` on your system - the value should be unique, and greater than 100.

Comment: can you type specific steps

Comment: I  suspect  the existence of the users in my terminal after writing
`compgen -u `
  then i decided to remove them and i removed _apt and this problem show up

Comment: awesome, just by creating the user, it fixed this issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can re-create the `_apt` user by using the following command:

```
sudo adduser --force-badname --system --no-create-home _apt
```

It doesn't matter what you put for the password or any other fields.

Then, `apt` will continue to work as normal.